# gdbserver loading symbol table from remote file

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I am trying to use gdbserver...
I have an application with binary path `/user/bin/foo` running with pid `19767`.

Started the gdbserver on remote:

```
gdbserver  --remote-debug --multi 0:12347
```

Started gdb on client and connected it to remove server

```
target extended-remote 192.168.1.84:12347
```

Attached gdb on pid

```
attach 19767
```

It shows:

```
warning: Could not load vsyscall page because no executable was specified
try using the "file" command first.
0x00007f207550043c in ?? ()
```

Also, current thread information it is showing is incorrect. Like info threads shows 1 thread , but my app has 10 threads-

```
(gdb) info threads
* 1 Thread 19767.19767  0x00007f207550043c in ?? ()
```

How can I ask gdb to load symbol from remote file `/user/bin/foo`? How to make it show correct info?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014288/gdb-remote-debugging-cant-seem-to-find-symbols

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I ask gdb to load symbol from remote file /user/bin/foo

You can't. Copy remote `/usr/bin/foo` locally (or mount the filesystem it's on), and then invoke gdb like this: `gdb /path/to/copy/of/foo`, or just use the `file` command.

Comment: is it sufficient to copy `/usr/bin/foo` or should i also copy all the libs linked to it that have debug symbols?

Answer (score 6):

As of gdb 7.10, you can use

```
set sysroot target:
```

to make gdb retrieve files from the remote filesystem. See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#Files