# how to use --add-gnu-debuglink to keep gdb symbol files in a mounted folder

Tags: linux, debugging, ubuntu, gdb, gdbserver

This is wrt Ubuntu setup.

In short, if I use command "*objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=/mntsymbols/binsymbol/prog.debug  prog*" it does not work and while doing gdb, symbols are not found.
gdb gets symbols only if prog.debug is in same folder as prog.
Things work after I do *gdb> symbol-file /mntsymbols/binsymbol/prog.debug*

/mntsymbols is mounted folder from remote machine.
prog is stripped binary.
prog.debug is debug symbol file for prog created using "*objcopy --only-keep-debug*".

I am trying to setup a gdb symbol server for a simple test program.
sys1 is gdb symbol server. Will keep symbol files as 
sys1:/root/symboldir/testp1symbols/prog.debug
sys1:/root/symboldir/testp1symbols/shared1.so.debug

Will mount sys1:/root/symboldir/ on sys2, and I should be able debug using gdb on sys2. how to achieve this using --add-gnu-debuglink or any other way.

Comment: Have you tried this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15556670/7561577)?

Comment: As per this answer it is recommending to bring remote file to local and then use it. where as I specifically want to use remote debug symbol file. Also file command allows to load only one symbol file. where as a program in general can require more than one symbol file if it used shared(so) files.

Comment: Also, In my case mounting remote directory (that contained symbol files) did not help.

Comment: I use `set solib-search-path /path/to/the/shared/libs`

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html).

You should use `--add-gnu-debuglink=prog.debug` and set `debug-file-directory` in GDB to `/mntsymbols/binsymbol`.

The way you have set this up, GDB probably looks for `prog.debug` in `/usr/lib/debug/mntsymbols/binsymbol`. You can verify this by running GDB itself under `strace -e open`.

Comment: When I did --add-gnu-debuglink=prog.debug I had to keep prog.debug in same directory, else command was failing. Then I kept prog.debug in default dir /usr/lib/debug as well as /mntsymbols/binsymbol. While using gdb, did 'set debug-file-directory' and made sure using 'show debug-file-directory'. (I added this to ~/.gdbinit also). But still it does not find symbols. May be I need to reload all the symbols after doing set debug-file-directory, I had read it but lost the commands.

Comment: I have not tried strace trick you mentioned. will try and post.

Comment: In my case if I set debug-file-directory to `/some-dir`, then gdb was searching symbol file in `/some-dir/dir1/dir2/` for the original file in `/dir1/dir2`.